# Plaid node SDK sandboxPublicTokenCreate() returning INVALID_PUBLIC_TOKEN

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, plaid

I'm trying to use sandboxPublicTokenCreate() to get a public token to use in my tests, but I keeps returning a 400 error like:

```js
data: {
          display_message: null,
          documentation_url: 'https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#invalid-input-errors',
          error_code: 'INVALID_PUBLIC_TOKEN',
          error_message: 'provided public token is in an invalid format. expected format: public-<environment>-<identifier>',
          error_type: 'INVALID_INPUT',
          request_id: '2yEEbS5QI993pZj',
          suggested_action: null
        }
```

I've followed the example docs at https://plaid.com/docs/api/sandbox/ and tried manually executing the request with Axios, with same result:

Here's my code:

```js
import { Configuration, PlaidApi, PlaidEnvironments, Products, SandboxPublicTokenCreateRequest } from 'plaid'

/**
   * Returns a public token we can use for testing tied to the Royal Bank of Plaid
   *
   * @returns {Promise<string>}
   * @memberof BankAccountService
   */
  public async getPublicTokenForTesting(): Promise<string> {
    const institutionId = 'ins_117650'
    const initialProducts = [Products.Assets, Products.Balance]

    const publicTokenRequest: SandboxPublicTokenCreateRequest = {
      institution_id: institutionId,
      initial_products: initialProducts
    }

    try {
      const CONFIG = new Configuration({
        basePath: PlaidEnvironments[process.env.PLAID_ENV],
        baseOptions: {
          headers: {
            'PLAID-CLIENT-ID': process.env.PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
            'PLAID-SECRET': process.env.PLAID_SECRET
          }
        }
      })

      const client = new PlaidApi(CONFIG)
      const publicTokenResponse = await client.sandboxPublicTokenCreate(publicTokenRequest)
      const publicToken = publicTokenResponse.data.public_token

      return publicToken
    } catch (e) {
      console.error({ response: e.response })
    }
```

Comment: Can you console.log the `publicTokenResponse`? What is it?

Comment: @Alex It's not getting that far. It's getting a 400 inside of `sandboxPublicTokenCreate()`

Comment: The error you posted looks like a response to `/link/token/create`, but if it's a response to `/sandbox/public_token/create`, can you log the request that's being generated to `/sandbox/public_token/create`? (With the client ID and secret redacted, of course.) You should also be able to find the request on the activity log on the Plaid dashboard at dashboard.plaid.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I was using Polly to record requests and it was replaying a bad response. Will close this as soon as SO lets me.